# Let $f: N -> N$ be a fucntion satisfying $f(n+m) = f(n) + f(m)$ for all $m$ and $n$. Prove that there exist a constant $c$ so that $f(n) = cn$.

Tags: combinatorics, induction

The question is actually Example 2.6 from *A walk through combinatorics*. The solution given below is exactly as in book.

> Let $m = 0$, then $f(n + 0) = f(n) + f(0)$, so $f(0) = 0$, and the base case is 
>   complete. Now let us assume that we know the statement is true for all natural 
>   numbers less than or equal to $n$. That is, there exists a constant $c$ so 
>   that $f(k) = ck$ if $k \leq n$. In particular, that means $f(1) = c$ and
>   $f(n) = cn$. This implies that $f(n+1) = f(n) + f(1) = cn + c = c(n+1)$, and 
>   the statement is proved.

Is the proof correct? I mean in induction it uses the fact that $f(1) = c$ which is not proven in the base step. And even if we try to prove it the similar way as we are doing in induction step for $f(n+1)$, we will get $f(1 + 0) = f(0) + f(1)$, thus $f(1) = f(1)$ not $f(1) = c$ which we want.

Comment: That $f(1)=c$ is automatic, since it is a function and it is well defined, so $1$ is sent to some unique natural number $c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(1)$ has to equal something,  Call it $c$.

Answer (score 0):

If that induction step is difficult to understand, you can do it directly and see why $f(1) = c$ (it's not a given constant, it's what you'll have to show):

$$f(n) = f(n-1 + 1) = f(n-1) + f(1) = f(n-2)+f(1)+f(1) = \cdots = nf(1)$$

so that constant is indeed $f(1)$.